# sml code 3>4 orelse 5<6 andalso not 7<>8;

Tags: smlnj

3>4 orelse 5<6 andalso not 7<>8;

Please why is the above sml generating error as follow

- 3>4 orelse 5<6 andalso not 7<>8;
  stdIn:1.25-1.33 Error: operator and operand don't agree [overload conflict]
  operator domain: bool
  operand:         [int ty]
  in expression:

  ### not 7

Answer (score 2):

Your expressions is parsed as the following, because function application has higher precedence than any other binary operator:

```
3>4 orelse 5<6 andalso (not 7)<>8
```

Note the `(not 7)` part, which doesn't make sense. So, you have to explicitly say what's the argument to `not`:

```
3>4 orelse 5<6 andalso not (7<>8)
```